# Sub queries in Yii

Tags: mysql, yii

I have the following mysql query which works well in phpmyadmin when i execute it :

```
"SELECT * FROM accounts_users WHERE id = ( SELECT teacher_id FROM general_teacher_student_associations WHERE student_id = 509 )";
```

But when i execute via Yii, it breaks :

```
    $query          = "SELECT * FROM accounts_users WHERE id = ( SELECT teacher_id FROM general_teacher_student_associations WHERE student_id =509 )";
    $command        = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
    $teachers_list  = $command->query();
    return $teachers_list;
```

509 is a dynamically fetched value.

**1. What am i doing wrong?**

**2. Can this be done in a better way?**

```
/******Edited***********/
```

Found the error : The sub query returns more than one row. Can i use single query to fetch all the values other than using a foreach loop and then inside that executing another query?

### **Solution :**  (Accepting Daniels answer since his comment actually solved the issue)

```
    $query          = "SELECT * FROM accounts_users WHERE id IN ( SELECT teacher_id FROM general_teacher_student_associations WHERE student_id =509 )";
    $command        = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
    $teachers_list  = $command->queryAll();
    return $teachers_list;
```

p.s: This is an edition work and i am not allowed to touch model and hence using model relations is out of window and thats why i ended up with this

Comment: What does "it breaks" mean?

Comment: I am working with a nightmare code and even though its Yii framework, every action is done through jquery click events and through that by calling Yii controller and so on.. So when i execute it, on console, it gives a 500 error. If i comment out this, it works. I cannot debug much from this.

Comment: and with queryAll()? : $teachers_list  = $command->queryAll();

Comment: how are you passing the dynamic value to your query?

Comment: FRom controller i am calling out this function which is in API folder. And in that fucntion, i pass it as an argument like $teachers = $this->studioApi->findTeacherDetailsOfStudent($_SESSION['user_id']); And yes session exists.

Comment: Enable proper error logging, look at the logs to see what specifically causes the error.

Comment: Okay i think the Sub Query returns more than 1 row. Can i do something so that i dont use foreach and this can be handled via single query itself?

Comment: If a subquery returns more than one row, then you need to decide what you want to do - get all the teachers (in some particular order), get only one of them (based on some specific ordering), or something else. Daniel's answer is pretty close to what you need, except it doesn't have the `WHERE` clause and fetches only a single row.

Comment: If the SubQuery return many results you need a "IN" clausule instead of "="

Comment: Yes i saw that and got it. but i would need all list of teachers. Can i do something so that instead of using two queries(fetching teacher list and then getting individual teacher details inside for each loop), can i do it in a single query? When i did the above mentioned one, i felt it was not a proper way..

Comment: @Daniel : Awesome. It worked...Thanks a lot.. If you can edit the answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$teachers_list = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('ausers.*')
        ->from('accounts_users ausers')
        ->join('( SELECT teacher_id FROM general_teacher_student_associations WHERE student_id = 509 ) as teachers ON teachers.teacher_id = ausers.id')
        ->queryRow();
```